# IE não resolve URL

Tags: asp.net, url, dns

Publiquei uma aplicação em asp.net c# na minha Intranet. Entrando pela URL, a aplicação funciona pelo Chrome, Firefox e pelo IE dá erro no meio da aplicação e não executa certas funcionalidades. Porém, se no próprio IE eu digitar o IP ao invés da URL, a aplicação funciona perfeitamente. 
Por que isso acontece? Alguma ideia de como resolver isso?

Comment: Quantos caracteres tem a URL? Há parâmetros nela?

Comment: @Renan a url é assim: **ti_hom.xxxxxx.yyyyy.br**   Nesse molde e com essa mesma quantidade de caracteres.

Comment: Em determinado momento da aplicação a url carrega parametros sim...

Comment: É nesses momentos que o IE falha?

Comment: Não @Renan falha sem parametros também...

Comment: Ah, importante... Qual é a versão do IE? Talvez os componentes nas páginas não suportem se for versão antiga.

Comment: Estou usando IE 10 @Renan. Já coloquei no código da aplicação até a tag **<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />**

Comment: @TiagoSilva mas esse algo específico que não seria compatível com IE não rodaria no IE nem puxando pelo IP não? Através do IP a aplicação funciona perfeitamente no IE

Comment: javascript e css tem sim. Mas algo pode ser compatível pelo IE se ao invés de entrar com IP eu entrar com a URL ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que li nos comentários, a estrutura da sua url é `ti_hom.xxxxxx.yyyyy.br` e o problema está justamente nisso: [o internet explorer tem problemas com urls que contém _ (*underscore*)](http://www.schwammysays.net/problems-with-underscore-in-urls/).

Tradução de uma parte pertinente do artigo linkado:

> [...] o *underscore* é um caractere aceitável em uma url [...]
>   Contudo, o IE parece não gostar dele quando o mesmo faz parte do nome
>   do domínio ou subdomínio [...] O problema acontece quando você precisa
>   usar cookie no site, coisa que a maioria dos sites precisam,
>   especialmente se você está usando cookies como parte do esquema de
>   validação. O IE não consegue criar cookies quando o nome do domínio ou
>   do subdomínio tem um *underscore*

Infelizmente [parece que não existe solução para isso](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/316112/en-us?wa=wsignin1.0) além de mudar o nome do seu domínio ou instruir seus usuários a usarem o endereço de IP diretamente/ trocar de browser. Todas alternativas podem ser problemáticas, então cabe a você decidir qual caminho tomar.

Comment: Tinha pensado nessa hipótese William Barbosa. Esse problema com o underscore seria só no nome do domínio mesmo ou também no caminho e sub pastas da aplicação? Tipo **ti_hom.xxxxxx.yyyyy.br/Home/_Adm** ?

Comment: O problema ocorre somente em domínio e subdomínio. Apesar do uso de _underscore_ como separador não ser uma boa prática se você tiver interesse em SEO.

Comment: Excelente resposta! Já tive esse mesmo problema antes e não lembrava disso.

Comment: Show de bola! Vou criar outra url então e testar.

Comment: Perfeito @WilliamBarbosa